# what do folks think of help finding curated data questions?

Tags: discussion

I was about to pose such question and It occurs to me finding curated data questions are not really programming related so much as about guessing how something might be categorized in some undocumented hidden database.

This is potentially annoying and maybe should be off topic. What do people think?

Example ( and a back door way to get my question in ) I was trying to accomplish a seemingly trivial task of generating a list of US States:

```
AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Ohio", "UnitedStates"}, "Subdivisions"]
```

gives the counties in the a state.

```
 AdministrativeDivisionData[{"UnitedStates",  "Country"}, "Subdivisions"]
 AdministrativeDivisionData[{"UnitedStates"}, "Subdivisions"]
 AdministrativeDivisionData[ Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"],
   "Subdivisions"]
```

all fail..

```
 CountryData["UnitedStates"]["Properties"]
```

shows a lot of stuff but no state list..

Anyway on meta I don't really need to answer that so much as ask if that's an acceptable type of question.

Comment: Curate data is a big part of what WRI offers, so I think questions like this are on topic for the main site

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Questions on the main site are not limited to programming issues. I see no reason to reject the kind of question you propose. We have already had some. Here is [one such](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133880/) that I remember because I posted an answer.